# can't set background-image with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some jQuery code:

```
var imgone="url(../img/ico1.jpg)";
jQuery("#img1 .imgset").css('background-image',imgone);
```

For some reason it doesn't seem to change the background image, just making it blank.
Does anyone have any suggestions to make it work?

Comment: Does `../img/ico1.jpg` exist relative to the path of the page you're trying to do this in?

Comment: Check in network tab if you have a 404 error for your image.

Comment: yes, my page has an external js file in the 'js' folder. I've tried both `../img/ico1.jpg` and `img/ico1.jpg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the image file is missing, check your path. You can look for `404` errors in your browser's development console. Also note, that your image path should be relative to the **page** that executes the script, not relative to the script file.

Also be sure that you can *actually see* the background of the element you're modifying. For example, if you have `<img src="...">` then setting `background-image` on this `<img>` will have no effect, since what you see is the contents of the image, not its background.

Also you can use a leading slash to specify a path relative to your domain's root. That is, you can put `url(/img/ico1.jpg)` (note the leading slash) and this will be the path not relative to your html-file, but, in a sense, absolute.

Comment: I'm using a <div> tag: `<div id="img1"><div class="imgset"></div></div>` with this as it's css: `.imgset
{
 border-color:#4f4f4f;
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:thin;
 -moz-border-radius:7px;
 border-radius:7px;
 height:25px;
 width:25px;
 position:absolute;
 float:left;
 background-image:url(../img/blank.jpg);
}`

Comment: @user2422350 just check your console (Ctrl+Shift+C in Chrome) for 404 errors. Most likely, the path is wrong. Or simply ensure that if you add `<img src="../img/ico1.jpg">` next to your `div` the image will show up.

Comment: Thanks, later on in the script I had re-set the variable as a different file.

Answer (score 0):

Check the image file path. It looks like you are trying to go up a folder with ../ Is it necessary?

Comment: ../ is necessary as the image is located in the img folder and the script is located in another folder called js

Comment: So then, no. It isn't necessary. The above code will be executed on the root of the site and from there you will just go down to img!!! Remember you are changing inline styles and not the css file...